# no-unneccessary-generics on updating a TS interface on DefinitelyTyped (DTSLint)

Tags: typescript, tslint

I tried to use a specific library (query-string) but when I noticed that the 'parse' function was returning me an *any* type I decided to update the type definitions in order to add a generic.

So, I went to DefinitelyTyped repository, forked it, and updated this definition

```
export function parse(str: string, options?: ParseOptions): any;
```

to

```
export function parse<T>(str: string, options?: ParseOptions): T;
```

But then, when I tried to compile I got this error:

https://github.com/Microsoft/dtslint/blob/master/docs/no-unnecessary-generics.md

Can somebody explain it to me? I really don't understand why it should give problems? I'm really forced to cast it on my personal project?

Answer (score 0):

In your case generic parameter is unnecessary because it doesn't help to describe inner logic of the function.
You can make same type coercion using external option.
Generic parameter make sense only if it can't be removed from function or class signature

```
// Bad. Generic can be removed
function parse<T>(): T;
const x = parse<number>();

// Good. No unnecessary generic
function parse(): {};
const x = parse() as number;

// Good. Generic can't be removed
function identity<T>(arg: T): T {
    return arg;
}
```

Comment: Is it really better to cast externally than having a typed output? It's like having returning Object on C# and then casting it externally to whatever you need?